# How to avoid event reflection by pub/sub?

Tags: javascript, events, data-binding, publish-subscribe, broadcast

I want to keep various data sources in sync. To do that I want to broadcast change events using an event hub. So in this structure every data source can be a publisher and a subscriber of events either. Currently I don't have an implementation, I am just thinking on how to do that.

I have problem to figure out how to prevent event reflection (infinite loop in other terms). So by a data source

```
-> ds.change -> hub.publish(ds, event) -> hub.subscriber[x] = ds.sync(event)
-> ds.change -> ... //infinite loop caused by sync triggered change event
```

This is a basic reflection (in my terms), this can be avoided by simply ignoring the same events from the same ds (data source) on the hub until the current event handling process is done. But how should we know when it is done?

By sync code we can simply cover the process with a transaction and check if the current ds is already synchronized or not. If yes then ignore it. What if we have 2 hubs synchronizing the same 2 data sources:

```
-> ds.change -> hub1.publish(ds, event) -> hub.subscriber[x] = ds2.sync(event)
-> ds2.change -> hub2.publish(ds2, event2) -> hub2.subscriber[x] = ds.sync(event2)
-> ds.change -> ... //infinite loop caused by signal sent back by the other hub
```

So we have to cover the 2 hubs with the same transaction. So we have to use some sort of global transaction.

Now all of these can be solved more or less with a sync code. But what about an async code? How can I end a transaction if I cannot determine exactly when I should do that? Ending a transaction too early or too late would cause an invalid application state. Adding a transaction id to the events and never ending the transaction would cause a memory leak. Any idea?

### Conclusion

The async part of the problem is very hard and it is more about concurrent threads, thread safety and parallel programming then simple event handling. So I decided to accept T.J. Crowder's answer, because it is a genius idea to compare the values instead of creating a global transaction object. If you have a general solution for the async part of the problem, please share it with us!

I asked the same question on here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/241599/how-to-avoid-oscillation-by-async-event-based-systems and I got there a more general answer about how to prevent state oscillations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a publisher only raises an event when something *changes*, you'll avoid infinite loops **if** you can be guaranteed that subscribers receive earlier events before receiving later events. You can ensure that guarantee with either synchronous or asynchronous event dispatch; in the latter case, it's more work, because subscribers have to acknowledge having received an event before you give them the next one. Basically subscribers need to have a FIFO queue of pending events.

Suppose `A` subscribes to change events for `x` from `B`, and `B` subscribes to change events for `x` from `A`. Then something changes `A.x`:

1. `A` sees the `x` value changed, saves the new value, and raises a change.
2. `B` sees the event from `A`, compares the `x` on the event with its own, sees they're different, saves it, and raises a change.
3. `A` sees the change event from `B`, compares the `x` on the event with its own, sees they're the same, and doesn't do anything.

If you can't have that guarantee, then you run into the problem you describe below: `A` could raise an event changing `x` to `1`, then raise another event changing `x` to `2`, and if `B` sees the `x=>2` change prior to the `x=>1` change, `A` and `B` could end up in a never-ending cycle.

Comment: Ahm, so you say I should compare the values before doing anything with them?

Comment: Nice idea, it should work perfectly in this special case if there are no concurrent events running the same time in an async system... :-)

Comment: Imagine an async data synchronization solution. In that you send 2 events right after each other. The first one changes a value to x and the second one changes the same value to y. Now by an async system some parts of the system can be in x state when they meet the y event and other parts of the system can be in y state when they meet the x event. So they keep changing parts of the system from x to y and vica versa... This is an infinite loop either. By sync code you cannot have these inconsistencies...

Comment: I think the async part of the problem is more about thread safety then simple event handling. I was looking for something simple, so I think I accept your solution, and forget the async part.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a very good point. You could indeed bounce constantly from x to y. And I don't think you need it to be a multi-threaded environment, either. (Virtually no JavaScript environments are multi-threaded in the classic sense; certainly not browsers or NodeJS.) Just async (without multiple threads) could easily cause the problem you describe. So I don't think this solution works.

Comment: Yes it is similar to dropping a stone into a cup of water, but it will never end reflecting the wave of events... Your solution is perfect for sync events, I should have come up with the same idea, that's why I accepted it.

Comment: @inf3rno: For what it's worth, I've updated to flag up the issues.

Comment: I remember on a similar phenomenon by reaction kinetics: oscillating chemical reactions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WasYuiOk5xQ that was funny too... :-)

Comment: I have another answer here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/242608/65755 if you are interested.